# WebApi not serializing class inheriting from Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have a class that inherits from Exception, and it's decorated with `[Serializable]` and also implements `ISerializable`:

```
    protected MyException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info != null)
        {
            this.MyProperty = (Dictionary<string, string>)info.GetValue("MyProperty ", typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));
        }
    }

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);

        if (info != null)
        {
            info.AddValue("MyProperty ", this.MyProperty );
        }
    }
```

Everything was working as expected and this class was being serialized on the WebApi project and dersialized back on the client.

In the meantime I've updated all my Nuget packages (Newtonsoft, WebApi2, etc) and all of a sudden, serializing the class in the controllers' actions does not call the `ISerializable` constructor. Therefore the client doesn't find the custom properties on deserializing.

When serializing/deserializing the exception manually using `JsonConvert.Serialize` and `JsonConvert.Deserialize` (for testing purposes) everything works as expected. So this is not a problem on Json.Net but maybe something within the Asp.Net pipeline.

Could this problem be related with the latest update of the WebApi2 packages? Do I need to change my code or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: You forgot to call `: base(info, context)` in the constructor.  Beyond that, can you 1) share the complete code for the `MyException` class?  2) Tell us the exact version of Json.NET being used?  Both 11.0 and 12.0 have changes that can affect `Exception` serialization.

Comment: @dbc Did the call. Problem persists. My exception class is quite simple It just has a property of type `Dictionary<string, string>`. I'm using WebApi 5.2.7 and Json.Net 12.0.2. The problem is that `GetObjectData` is not being called anymore.

Comment: Leaking out exception data from a server is bad security practice, see: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121481/is-exposing-exception-information-in-web-service-a-security-risk  and https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=88487679#content/view/88487679

Comment: That's ok because it's an intraner app.